# Docker Swarm network overlay issue

Tags: networking, overlay, docker-swarm, portainer

I created 3 ubuntu 20.04 VM in Proxmox VE 7 for the docker swarm.  I tried to follow the site https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/ceinstallswarm/ to setup the Portainer on my Swarm.  However I can’t browse any IP address of the ubuntu VMs to access Portainer site to setup the docker container.

Something is go wrong on the overlay network on my swarm.  It looks like the ingress not enable.  Please see the below network inspect for portainer_agent_network.

And I found that all swarm machines not listen the port 4789.  When I run the command `sudo lsof -i:4789`, it shows nothing.

Does anyone help me to troubleshoot it?  What is going wrong on my docker swarm?

```
ubuntu@swarm01:~$ docker network inspect portainer_agent_network 
[
    {
        "Name": "portainer_agent_network",
        "Id": "tzm9sx2zifgaxhpmrd8xk7gti",
        "Created": "2021-08-07T14:24:33.835202371Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.11.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.11.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "54a9491638f699fc6441961b04b91c8ca923bd8e4980dbe36651fa2618cdbe2c": {
                "Name": "portainer_portainer.1.fd5m3wvccnxrl43iwst2imwti",
                "EndpointID": "4537774ec3c146843b48ab89707df7b04a6a76880af85dbe025fcc4d7422262c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:0b:0c",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.11.12/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "83044215d796b649ee8fc78be2d1364c80646448db3a933ee9a48ff0b0b7fe24": {
                "Name": "portainer_agent.idso1hec0iqiyvm1jhu1iaoq1.qidcsempp75po4znf1c7pj09r",
                "EndpointID": "dfdd91e83969150ea70674b9ea998690b47a6abf113c9a644315d641c6b68e1c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:0b:05",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.11.5/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-portainer_agent_network": {
                "Name": "portainer_agent_network-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "be0b5a8bdda9ccae975314fad1424d96e3c57763b1c145f4a67e286f54300195",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:0b:08",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.11.8/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4107"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "0589007b93f4",
                "IP": "10.0.0.241"
            },
            {
                "Name": "be83a3dd8fbd",
                "IP": "10.0.0.242"
            },
            {
                "Name": "f937ea4c2dbf",
                "IP": "10.0.0.243"
            }
        ]
    }
]

ubuntu@swarm01:~$ sudo lsof -i:7946
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dockerd 451 root   30u  IPv6  14558      0t0  TCP *:7946 (LISTEN)
dockerd 451 root   32u  IPv6  14559      0t0  UDP *:7946 
ubuntu@swarm01:~$ sudo lsof -i:4789
ubuntu@swarm01:~$
```

Thanks with the best regards,

Patrick Lee

Answer (score 0):

The overlay network is a virtual network that the nodes use to communicate with each other internally.

If you want any traffic that's external to the swarm (including curl from the same VM) to reach your portainer containers, then you'll need to expose that port.

Using Docker CLI: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#publish-service-ports-externally-to-the-swarm--p---publish

or Docker Compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

Note: you want to expose these containers as services, not as individual containers.